# Stack Overflow returned HTTP 503

Tags: support, bug

I received a "503 Maximum threads for service reached" error twice today. What is this error and what causes this to occur?

[image]

Comment: I am accessing from Sri Lanka. Not Singapore or Indonesia?

Comment: Your traffic goes over singapore, which is indicated by the details.